Inferring function parameter types from generics
I have an issue of infering function parameters from generic types.
type CommentServices = {
  deleteComment: (commentId: string, parentCommentId?: string) => void;
};
export default function useComments<T extends CommentServices>(CommentServices: T) {
  const deleteComment = async (...args: Parameters<T["deleteComment"]>) => {

      await CommentServices.deleteComment(...args);

  };
}

When passing ...args to  CommentServices.deleteComment I got this error.
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

Playground.
Playground2 demonstrate why I need genric solution
TypeScript v4.5.4

This is more or less ms/TS#47615, but I'm confused about your intent here. Why is this generic at all? The obvious solution here is just to accept CommentServices and not T extends CommentServices as shown in this playground link. What is the generic doing for you?

cause i have multiple CommentServices for Posts  and Articles and so... and I have different apis but the logic is the same so I have it generic cause for example deletePostComment takes only CommetId but for Article it takes commentId and parentCommentId

Please [edit] to show an example of this and what fails when you use the nongeneric solution. It looks fine to me.

i've updated the playground with comments so you can get my point

Please either [edit] your question with the requisite information, or provide info in a comment. I don't know what you updated but I have no access to it. (Did you just do it on your own machine or something?) Your goal should be to demonstrate something that works how you want when you call the generic version but fails when you call the nongeneric version I suggested.  Otherwise the nongeneric solution is still the way to go here.

i've edited the question, add more playground explain why I need a generic solution and, thank you

I'm not sure why your demonstration shows a problem that matters, but assuming it does matter: the easiest approach is just a type assertion as shown here. More difficult but slightly safer is to change the generic as shown here. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?
